# Passing a address via intent to Google map activity

Tags: android

I am working on an app that gets the address of an event the user selects. The address is a String and is passed from one activity to a Google Map activity. The problem is that the string doesn't arrive to my google map activity.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

How i pass the string

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,MappaActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("nome_azienda ","parigi");
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

How i get it

```
nomeAzienda = getIntent().getStringExtra("nome_azienda");
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you passing the string you have a space at the end of the parameter "nome_azienda "

```
intent.putExtra("nome_azienda ","parigi");
```

Change to

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,MappaActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("nome_azienda","parigi");
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
```